# youtube like comment using css

Tags: html, css

I am very much new in css html.
I am trying to something like the youtube comment display system using css. something like this. Where there would be an image of the comment poster then name and the comment text beside. So far I have been able to do is this [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/samiul_anik/pen/EaOqrY)

```css
.vjs-comment-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 3;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 250px;
  -moz-user-select: text !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
.comment-user-name {
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  font-size: 10;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
.comment-profile-pic {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>
    <div class="comment-profile-pic">
    </div>
    <div class="comment-user-name">
      User 1
    </div>
    <div class="vjs-comment-list">
      testing comments testing comments testing comments testing comments testing comments testing comments testing commentstesting comments
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="comment-profile-pic">
    </div>
    <div class="comment-user-name">
      User 1
    </div>
    <div class="vjs-comment-list">
      testing comments testing comments testing comments testing comments testing comments testing comments testing commentstesting comments
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Where the comments and user name are below the picture of the user. Could anyone help me on how to have text and user name like the youtube.  [image]

Comment: Here is the codepen link     http://codepen.io/samiul_anik/pen/EaOqrY

Comment: You haven't asked a question... Also, to insert a link in your post, do this: `[label](http://example.com/asdf)`.

Comment: Okay, now you have a question, but it's kind of broad. What's something specific that you want to change about what you have?

Comment: My bad I could not explain my problem. I want to have the user name and the text beside the image. just like youtube have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't define explicitly position on the element its default position is static with this position you can't use top/bottom/left/right properties, if you want to achieve this using positioning try to add to .comment-profile-pic and .comment-user-name  position: absolute and to their container position relative.

like this:

```
.comment-profile-pic {
     position: absolute;
     .
     .
     .
     top: 1%;
     left: 2%
 }
```

and so on.

Also you can use float (add to image's css rule float: left) as a option: